Docker Compose PostgreSQL Data Persistence Not Working as Expected
I'm having trouble with data persistence in my Docker Compose setup for a Spring Boot application that uses PostgreSQL. The data persists only when I stop the PostgreSQL container individually and start it again, but when I bring the entire Docker Compose stack down and then up again, the data is lost.
Here's my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: jwt_security
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"

  app:
    image: my-spring-app # Replace with your actual Spring Boot app image name
    container_name: spring-boot-app
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/jwt_security
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Adjust if your Spring Boot app runs on a different port

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    external: true

Steps I Have Tried:

Remove Existing Containers and Volumes:
docker-compose down -v
docker volume rm postgres-data


Create the External Volume:
docker volume create --name postgres-data


Bring Up the Containers:
docker-compose up



Problem:
After setting up the environment and adding data to the database, I can see the data using:
docker exec -it postgres-container psql -U postgres -d jwt_security
SELECT * FROM _user;

However, when I run docker-compose down and then docker-compose up, the data is lost. Here are the details of what I observe:

The external volume seems to be created and used correctly.
When I inspect the volume, it appears to be mounted correctly.
Logs from the PostgreSQL container indicate the database system initializes correctly but does not retain data.


In the "Problem" section, you are utilizing docker exec. I don't think this will run an instance of the service defined in docker. To do that, you may need to use docker compose exec postgres. If you were just trying to make a small image that would be removed after debugging, it does not appear that you are mounting the volume to this. Have you tried including --mount source=postgres-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data?

I believe you need to run docker volume create postgres-data, note: without the --name flag. This is how I have done it in the past and checking the --help for the volume create command does now show a --name flag.
> docker volume create --help

Usage:  docker volume create [OPTIONS] [VOLUME]

Create a volume

Options:
  -d, --driver string   Specify volume driver name (default "local")
      --label list      Set metadata for a volume
  -o, --opt map         Set driver specific options (default map[])


I tried, but it still not work, the result same
